# AWS Lambda Hot and Cold Start

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Hello I am new to AWS Lambda.I want to know what do we mean by Hot Lambda function (Hot Start) and Cold Lambda function (Cold Start) ?? Can anyone please explain me in detail & what is the difference between Hot Lambda and Cold Lambda

Answer (score 18, accepted):

After uploading your code or after periods of inactivity your Lambda is shut down or "cold". When a new event comes in there is a brief moment where Lambda spins up a new instance of your code - this includes whatever initializing AWS does to start up the "container" as well as initializing the code that you uploaded.

So an event that is able to hit an initialized("hot") Lambda will in theory be processed faster than hitting a cold one. There isn't a guarantee on how long a Lambda will stay hot after the last event but it could be as long as 5 minutes.

Comment: Also note that if you increase the amount of memory, AWS Lambda will start faster when it has a cold start. So increase lambda memory for infrequent visits, and decrease it when you have more traffic and your lambdas are warm

Comment: @adnan, can you explain why increasing memory allows the Lambda to start faster? I have noticed that Lambdas that only use a fraction of the available memory (e.g. 30-40%) still suffer from slow cold starts (~6s when cold vs 2ms when hot).

Comment: @CarlosMacasaet I think it is because the CPU is raised together with the memory. More memory means a bigger underlying virtual computer.

Comment: Is this still an issue in 2017? And is the solution the same, just crank up the dial on "memory?"

Comment: @Costa yes, according to the Lambda FAQ. https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/faqs/ "In the AWS Lambda resource model, you choose the amount of memory you want for your function, and are allocated proportional CPU power and other resources."

Comment: @Ryan Are there any events for container lifecycle ?

Answer (score 0):

It's a common belief that when people refer to "warm starts" they mean that the same container/sandbox is ready to receive a new connection - but that's not accurate.

- **Warm Start** - invoking a function using a warm container with a prebaked unused sandbox resources from previous invocations are not recycled.
- **Cold Start** - invoking a function when no container/sandbox is ready to receive the request. A new container must be created and the runtime and user code loaded. Cold start's latency is mostly an internal metric, externally, cold starts are only a part of the total overhead that can affect the end-user experience. In some scenarios, we can encounter a portion of the full cold start, think about scale prediction and statistical algorithms

However, using the terms "cold start" and "warm start" might be misleading, as a developer you should care about "Invocation Overheads" - The time it takes to call the user's function and return the response.

Answer (score 0):

Execution of Lambda requires preconfigured environment. This execution environment gets created based on

1. Memory
2. Max out or time out for function
3. Configuration parameters , dependencies to run code etc

provided by the user.

Cold start means a new environment is created to run function. Since creation of environment takes time it adds to lag

Warm start means reusing the environment earlier created to run function again ,since this time,  no time was spent on environment creation, responce is faster.

You can minimize cold start by setting up optimum Provisioned concurrency i.e. to define no of pre-initialized environment.